# How to know whether its a tablet or phone in android programmatically?

Tags: android, device, tablet, screen-size, android-screen

I would like to get to detect whether the given device is a tablet or phone in android.I have tried the two in the simulator but none worked. Both are here:

First

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) 
{
    //code
}
```

Second

```
    private boolean isTabletDevice() 
{         
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) 
    { 
    // honeycomb                    
    // test screen size, use reflection because isLayoutSizeAtLeast is only available since 11     
    Configuration con = getResources().getConfiguration();              
    try {                     
            Method mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast = con.getClass().getMethod("isLayoutSizeAtLeast");    
            Boolean r = (Boolean) mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast.invoke(con, 0x00000004); // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE    
            return r;              
        } catch (Exception x)
        {    
            return false;          
        }             
    }            
    return false;                   
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned above the two methods above I tried,it didnt work...I would like to get it from android program only not using user-agents...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code. You can get the screen inches

```
    String inputSystem;
    inputSystem = android.os.Build.ID;
    Log.d("hai",inputSystem);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
    int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
    Log.d("hai",width+"");
    Log.d("hai",height+"");
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(width/dm.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(height/dm.ydpi,2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
    Log.d("hai","Screen inches : " + screenInches+"");
```

Answer (score 6):

create two layout folders in **res** folder like this **layout** and **layout_xlarge**.Create one unwanted view in **layout-xlarge** file.Get this unwanted view id programatically.Access that unwanted id in code within **try catch** blocak if you get **null pointer exception** then it is **small device** otherwise it is **tablet**.one more thing hide the unwanted view in layout-xlarge screen.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first question to answer is what you mean by "phone" or "tablet". We may have some distinction in our minds, but in reality, your application should not care. The Asus Transformer is a tablet, the Samsung Galaxy Nexus is a phone. What is the [Samsung Galaxy Note](http://www.abc.net.au/technology/articles/2012/03/27/3464648.htm)? Engadget and others call it a "*phablet*" -- what should your application assume in that case?

Is your definition of "tablet" any device that does not have a SIM card? That is also a faulty definition because there are many tablets that do have a built in SIM card. Is your definition of "tablet" any device that defaults to landscape mode and *rotates* to portrait mode? Perhaps that is one approach but I doubt that is sufficient since there could be tablets that default to portrait, or worse, have square form factors in future.

In my opinion, the best way to handle this is to use [Android's guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) and switch on UI layouts. If you think you have a clear definition of tablets versus phones and absolutely need to detect one over the other, you probably need to do something like extract the model name [from the browser's user agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5261472/562139) and then match it against a database of names of tablets that you maintain. I know. Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

place this method in onResume() and can check.

```
public double tabletSize() {

     double size = 0;
        try {

            // Compute screen size

            DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            float screenWidth  = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;

            float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi;

            size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) +

                                 Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));

        } catch(Throwable t) {

        }

        return size;

    }
```

generally tablets starts after 6 inch size.